# Rudin's RCA Q3.4

Tags: lp-spaces

I'm trying to solve the following question from Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis. (Chapter 3, question 4) :

> Suppose $f$ is a complex measurable function on $X$, $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X$, and
>   $$\varphi(p) ~=~ \int_X |f|^p \; d\mu ~=~ \|f\|_p^p,~~~~~~~~~~(0 < p < \infty).$$
>   Let $E := \big\{ p :~ \varphi(p) < \infty\big\}$. Assume $\|f\|_\infty > 0$.
>
> (a) If $r < p < s$, $r \in E$, and $s \in E$, prove that $p \in E$.
>
> (b) Prove that $\log(\varphi)$ is convex in the interior of $E$ and that $\varphi$ is continuous on $E$.
>
> (c) By (a), $E$ is connected. Is $E$ necessarily open ? Closed ? Can $E$ consist of a single point ? Can $E$ be any connected subset of
>   $(0,\infty)$ ?
>
> (d) If $r < p < s$, prove that $\|f\|_p \leq \max\big( \|f\|_r, \|f\|_s\big)$. Show that this implies the inclusion
>   $$ \mathcal{L}_r(\mu) \cap \mathcal{L}_s(\mu) ~\subseteq~\mathcal{L}_p(\mu).$$
>
> (e) Assume that $\|f\|_r < \infty$ for some $r < \infty$ and prove that $$ \|f\|_p \xrightarrow[p \rightarrow \infty]{}\|f\|_\infty.$$

I got a solution to (a), (d) and (e). While typing my question, MSE suggested me to look at [$a\mapsto \log\left(\lVert f\lVert_{1/a}\right)$ is a convex map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169693/a-mapsto-log-left-lvert-f-lvert-1-a-right-is-a-convex-map)
which seems to be related to (b). However I'm clueless about (c). Where should I start from ?

**Edit**

I believe the idea from [$a\mapsto \log\left(\lVert f\lVert_{1/a}\right)$ is a convex map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169693/a-mapsto-log-left-lvert-f-lvert-1-a-right-is-a-convex-map) can be applied to get a proof that
$p \mapsto \log\|f\|_{\frac{1}{p}}$ is continuous on the interior of $E$. But this is not quite what we are asked to demonstrate... I'm puzzled.

**Second Edit**

Based on zhw's answer, it appears that $E$ is not necessarily open, nor necessarily closed and that it can be a singleton. The question whether or not $E$ can be any connected subset of $(0,\infty)$ remains. But I think I can come up with a proof that it can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For (c ) consider the following Lebesgue measure situations:

1. $X=(0,1)$ with $f(x) = 1/x.$
2. $X=(0,1/2)$ with $f(x) = 1/[x(\ln x)^2].$
3. $X=(0,\infty),f(x) = [1/(x(\ln x)^2](\chi_{(0,1/2)}(x) + \chi_{(2,\infty)}(x)).$

Comment: From (1) I got that $E = (0,1)$ is open, so it is not necessarily closed. How do I proceed with (2) and (3)? I'm unable to determine where those integrals converge. Thank you!

Comment: @epsilon-emperor  Thanks for your comment. I see that I made a few mistakes back then and they survived until today. I edited to stay away from the singularity at $1.$ Now I think we're good to go. For 2. let $u=\ln x$ to do the integral. You should then get $E=(0,1].$ For 3. you should get $E=\{1\}.$ After seeing these examples, you might try to get $E=[a,b]$ for any $[a,b]\subset (0,\infty).$

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on (2) and (3)? I'm not the best when it comes to solving wild integrals and determining where they converge. For (2), we need to find $$\int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{x^p (\ln x)^{2p}} \ dx$$

Comment: @epsilon-emperor  Did you try $p=1$ there?

Comment: We can easily evaluate the integral for $p = 1$, but how does that help to determine the values of $p$ for which the integral converges?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor  If $a,b>0,$ then $x^a|\ln x|^b \to 0$ as $x\to 0^+.$ If $p>1,$ write $p=1+a.$ Then $x^p|\ln x)|^{2p} = x^1 x^a|\ln x)|^{2p},$ which is much smaller than $x.$

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer for the continuity of $\varphi.$

WLOG $f\ge 0.$ Let $A=\{f\le 1\},$ $B= \{f> 1\}.$ Suppose $[p,q]\subset E.$ Let $p_n\to p$ within $[p,q].$ Clearly $f^{p_n}\to f^p$ pointwise everywhere.

Now

$$\tag 1\int_X f^{p_n} = \int_X f^{p_n}\chi_{A} + \int_X f^{p_n}\chi_{B}.$$

Observe $f^{p_n}\chi_{A} \le f^{p}\chi_{A}$ and $f^{p_n}\chi_{B} \le f^{q}\chi_{B}.$ Since both $f^{p}\chi_{A}, f^{q}\chi_{B} \in L^1(X),$ the DCT implies the right side of $(1)$ converges to

$$\int_X f^{p}\chi_{A} + \int_X f^{p}\chi_{B} = \int_X f^{p}.$$

This implies $\varphi$ is continuous from the right at $p.$

Similarly, $\varphi$ is continuous from the left at $q.$ It follows that $\varphi$ is continuous on $E.$

Comment: I decided to post another answer, since the given problem consists of quite a few parts, each a problem in its own right. I think the continuity of $\varphi$ on $E$ is simpler without delving into the log-convexity of $\varphi.$

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer! Also, here is an interesting discussion about the continuity of $\varphi$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158888/to-prove-continuity-of-varphip-int-x-fp-d-mu-on-e-p-varphip

Comment: @epsilon-emperor No I didn't see that at all, til now.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to add something for $b)$ because I have been working on this problem too and want anyone else that searches for this problem to have easy access to. The first fact that we need is for any function $f\in L^\alpha$ and for any $\beta > 0$ that
$$||f||_\alpha^{\beta}= \Big(\int_X |f|^{\alpha}d\mu\Big)^{\beta/\alpha}=\Big(\int_X (|f|^{\beta})^{\alpha/\beta}d\mu\Big)^{\beta/\alpha} = || |f|^\beta||_{\alpha/\beta}$$
Thus $|f|^\beta\in L^{\alpha/\beta}$ if $f\in L^\alpha$. With this fact in mind, let $p,q\in int(E)$ and $t\in (0,1)$. Thus $f\in L^p$ and $f\in L^q$. Using the previous fact, we have that
\begin{align*}
||f||_p^{(1-t)p} &= || (|f|^{(1-t)p})||_{p/[(1-t)p]}= || (|f|^{(1-t)p})||_{1/(1-t)}\\
||f||_q^{tq} &= || (|f|^{tq})||_{q/tq}= || (|f|^{tq})||_{1/t}\\
\end{align*}
So we have that $|f|^{(1-t)p}\in L^{1/(1-t)}$ and $|f|^{tq}\in L^{1/t}$. Then as $$\frac{1}{1/(1-t)}+\frac{1}{1/t}=1-t+t = 1 $$
We can use Holder's inequality to see that $|f|^{(1-t)p+tq}\in L^1$ and that $$||(|f|^{(1-t)p+tq})||_1 \leq || (|f|^{(1-t)p})||_{1/(1-t)} || (|f|^{tq})||_{1/t}=||f||_p^{(1-t)p}||f||_q^{tq} = \varphi(p)^{1-t}\varphi(q)^t$$
At the same time we have that
$$\varphi((1-t)p+tq)=||f||_{(1-t)p+qt}^{(1-t)p+qt} = || (|f|)^{(1-t)p+qt}||_1$$
So if we take the $\log$ on both sides and use properties of the $\log$ then
$$
\begin{align*}\log(\varphi((1-t)p+tq)) &\leq \log(\varphi(p)^{1-t}\varphi(q)^t)\\
&=\log(\varphi(p)^{1-t}) + \log(\varphi(q)^t) \\
&= [1-t]\log(\varphi(p)) + t \log(\varphi(q))
\end{align*}$$
Since $p,q \in int(E)$ and $t\in (0,1)$ were arbitrary, we may conclude that $\log \varphi$ is a convex function on the interior of $E$. Now, $\log\varphi$ being convex implies that $\varphi$ is convex and hence is also continuous on $int(E)$.

Comment: You have shown continuity on $\text{int}(E)$, not $E$. How do you extend that to continuity on $E$?

Comment: See my new answer on the continuity of $\varphi.$