# Rudin's RCA; Exercise 3.4 Part (b) Only

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral, integral-inequality

I'm working from Rudin's $Real~And~Complex~Analysis$ (3rd Ed.) on my own -- more specifically on Exercise 4 from Chapter 3 which is partially restated below (slightly modified). I only reference part (b) of the exercise since this is the only part I'm struggling with. For the rest of the problem (namely part (a) and parts (c), (d) & (e) of the exercise), refer to [this link](https://59clc.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/real-and-complex-analysis.pdf) pointing to a free download of Rudin's book referenced above (see PG. 71 in his book), or see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707694/rudins-rca-q3-4), etc. Please note that I'm working out of this book exclusively, and all concepts, definitions, theorems, etc., therein is what I'm working with.

> **Exercise 3.4** Suppose $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ is a measure space, where $\mu$ is a positive measure, and suppose $f\!:\!X\!\rightarrow\!\mathbb{C}$ is a measurable function. At any $p_{0}\in(0,+\infty)$ we define $\varphi(p_{0}):=\big(\|f\|_{p_{0}}\big)^{p_{0}}\!\!={\displaystyle{\!\!\int_{X}|f|^{p_{0}}~\!d\mu}}$, as well as we define the set $E:=\big\{\widetilde{p}\in(0,+\infty):\varphi(\!~{\widetilde{p}}\!~)\!<\!+\infty\big\}$. We also assume that $\|f\|_{+\infty}\!>0$.
>
> (b) Prove that $\log(\varphi)$ is convex on the interior of $E$ as well as that $\varphi$ is continuous on $E$.

I'm having difficulty showing that $\varphi$ is continuous at all points in $E$. As far as my dilemma in particular, I graciously need help with an elaboration of the very last, strict, inequality found in [this proof](https://mathsock.wordpress.com/2016/09/21/rudin-rca-exercise-3-4/comment-page-1/#comment-12) for part (b) only. The estimate in that proof gives continuity on all of $E$ (note also that my comment is at the bottom of that webpage also requesting the same elaboration, to which I haven't received a response as of yet, and I figured I'd come here to see what I can find in order to move on in the book overall). In case the link for [this proof](https://mathsock.wordpress.com/2016/09/21/rudin-rca-exercise-3-4/comment-page-1/#comment-12) is broken (or breaks at some point in the future), I will provide the relevant part of the proof posted there below (also slightly modified) in regards to part (b) in particular.

> **//Proof (b):** Begin by letting $r,s\in E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{+}$ where $r<s$, and then fix $\lambda\in(0,1)$ arbitrarily in order to set $p=p_{\lambda}=(1-\lambda)r+\lambda s\in(r,s)$. By appealing to H$\ddot{\text{o}}$lder's inequality, we can now deduce that $\varphi(p)\leq\big(\varphi(r)\big)^{1-\lambda}\big(\varphi(s)\big)^{\lambda}\!<\!+\infty$. We can use this inequality to show the first part of (b) -- we need $\varphi>0$ on the interior of $E$, which is indeed the case since $\|f\|_{+\infty}\!>0$ (I showed this with a quick proof by contradiction), and so $\log(\varphi)$ is convex on the interior of $E$ yielding $\varphi$ is convex on the interior of $E$ and we can conclude $\varphi$ is continuous on the interior of $E$.
>
> In order to show that $\varphi$ is continuous at all points in $E$, we first let $\varepsilon>0$, and then we can find an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that the set $E_{N}:=\big\{\widetilde{x}\in X:|f(\widetilde{x})|>N\big\}\cup\big\{\widetilde{x}\in X:0<|f(\widetilde{x})|<\frac{1}{N}\big\}$ has measure less than $\varepsilon$ -- namely, $0\leq\mu(E_{N})<\varepsilon$, and this is indeed possible since $\|f\|_{+\infty}\!>0$. This being said, choose a $\delta>0$ such that $0\leq\text{min}\big\{|1-N^{\delta}|,\big|1-\frac{1}{N^{\delta}}\big|\big\}<\varepsilon$. Then, for any $x,y\in E$ where $|x-y|<\delta$ we estimate that:
>
> ${\displaystyle{|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)|=\bigg|\int_{X}|f|^{x}-|f|^{y}d\mu\bigg|=\bigg|\int_{E_{N}~\sqcup~X\backslash E_{N}}\!\!\!\!\!\!|f|^{x}-|f|^{y}d\mu\bigg|}}$
>
> ${\displaystyle{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\leq\bigg|\int_{E_{N}}|f|^{x}-|f|^{y}d\mu\bigg|+\bigg|\int_{X\backslash E_{N}}|f|^{x}-|f|^{y}d\mu\bigg|}}$
>
> ${\displaystyle{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~<2\varepsilon\big(\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)\big)}}$,
>
> which shows that $\varphi$ is continuous on $E$.

I can't seem to simplify everything properly in order to show the very last, strict inequality above ${\displaystyle{\bigg|\int_{E_{N}}|f|^{x}-|f|^{y}d\mu\bigg|+\bigg|\int_{X\backslash E_{N}}|f|^{x}-|f|^{y}d\mu\bigg|<2\varepsilon\big(\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)\big)}}$ holds. I was hoping, not only if this is correct, but to determine how to establish this, since this actually shows $\varphi$ is uniformly continuous on $E$ implying continuity on $E$ (right [?] -- it looks correct as $\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)<+\infty$ whenever $x,y\in E$). I figured we need to take the first integral ${\displaystyle{\bigg|\int_{E_{N}}|f|^{x}-|f|^{y}d\mu\bigg|}}$ and use our assumption that $\mu(E_{N})<\varepsilon$ in order to get ${\displaystyle{\bigg|\int_{E_{N}}|f|^{x}-|f|^{y}d\mu\bigg|<\varepsilon\big(\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)\big)}}$; additionally, I figured our choice of $\delta>0$ will enable us to show ${\displaystyle{\bigg|\int_{X\backslash E_{N}}|f|^{x}-|f|^{y}d\mu\bigg|<\varepsilon\big(\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)\big)}}$ as well -- I think I can do this alone, but, if I'm correct, then my difficult arises with the first integral...I'm stumped. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach is somewhat more simple. Let $H=\{x\in X:|f(x)|\leq1\}$. Then, $|f(x)|^p\chi_H(x)$ is non increasing and $|f(x)|^p\chi_{X\backslash H}(x)$ is non decreasing in $p$, at every $x\in X$. Then, if $p_0,p_1\in E,\ p_0<p_1$, by the dominated convergence theorem:
$$\lim_{p\to p_0,p\in E}\int_{X\backslash H}|f|^pd\mu = \int_{X\backslash H}|f|^{p_0}d\mu\quad (1)$$
Note that the limit $\lim_{p\to p_0^-}$ holds even if there is no $p_1>p_0$ in $E$. Similarly, if $p_0,p_1\in E,\ p_0>p_1$, then
$$\lim_{p\to p_0,p\in E}\int_{H}|f|^pd\mu = \int_{H}|f|^{p_0}d\mu\quad (2)$$
and the limit $\lim_{p\to p_0^+}$ always holds. I left the details to you.

Comment: Ty for you post, and leaving out details; I was too busy trying to come up with the mechanics to drive out the inequality (then work further once doing so) -- in other words you feel that the proof linked in my question could be incorrect for this part overall? I was starting to think this myself after posting. I started to realize that, even after showing the strict inequality holds (if possible) from the linked-proof in my question, getting rid of the quantity $\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)$ presents difficulty also. I thought of considering the $\sup(E)$, for example, but this need not be finite.

Comment: I thought about it and I realized that $2\varepsilon\big(\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)\big)$ is enough because of the convexity of $\log \varphi$

Comment: I'll keep working. My intent was to come back a few days after posting (I'm new to the chapter). I think your comment hints upon the elaboration I'm after, but I'm curious how to bring convexity of $\log(\varphi)$ into everything -- if you can elaborate that would help. So we've shown $\log(\varphi)$ is convex on the interior of $E$, but I'm confused on how the strict inequality was obtained initially on top of using your comment. I'll work through your initial solution first; then I can always go back secondarily based on anything posted afterwards, but at least I have a way out overall.

Comment: Veridian, I had a brief set back, but I've returned to this problem. As an upfront quick question, shouldn't we distinguish your set $E$, from the given set $E$ defined in the problem-statement to be precise?  In other words (I figured to ask first), but shouldn't we let, say, $E^{*}=\big\{x\in X:|f(x)|\leq 1\big\}$ since $E:=\big\{\widetilde{p}\in(0,+\infty):\varphi(\widetilde{p})<+\infty\big\}$ in the problem-statement? I figured to bring this up as I'm working through your solution above now, and I didn't want confusion to arise.

Comment: uuuppps I didn't notice that I used the same letter for both sets. I edited the post!

Comment: No worries =). Sorry to be a stickler also. I absolutely follow the entire concept of your solution, and I figured I'd ask to be completely sure as I'm putting together everything rigorously. Very elegant solution! Thank you again for leaving out details, as I like your proof much better than the one I found online in general...concise and completely relative to the material out of the book. Very much appreciated overall!